# Go encoding JSON from relfect.Value

Tags: json, reflection, encoding, go

Underneath encoding/json it uses relfect to encoding struct.

But How can I encoding something that is already a type of reflect.Value

Check out the code below:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Pwd string `json:"pwd"`
}

func main() {
    factory := map[string]reflect.Type{
        "Person":reflect.TypeOf(Person{}),
    }

    s := reflect.New(factory["Person"]).Elem()
    s.Field(0).SetString("Max")
    s.Field(1).SetString("Password")
    j, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

It out puts something like this:

```
[123 34 102 108 97 103 34 58 52 48 54 125]
```

What is these?
What is correct way to do this, I mean to get right json string from a reflect.Value type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `(reflect.Value).Interface()` to get a value of type `interface{}` which can be JSON-encoded:

```
j, err := json.Marshal(s.Interface())
```

As for your question:

```
[123 34 102 108 97 103 34 58 52 48 54 125]
```

is the string `{"flag":406}`, printed as a slice of bytes (which is what `json.Marshal` returns).

Comment: That I didn't know. Thanks for the tip, I'm sure I'll need it at some point soon!